# How to write js after using requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I wrote this in the header template :

```
<script data-main="/js/init.js" src="/js/require.js"></script>
```

In `/js/init.js` I required jquery and some other JS classes before the initial code.

But in the body I need to load some separated JS code, and it needs to use `jquery`. e.g. This is what it is before I used requirejs :

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#loginForm').submit(function(){
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

For some reason it cant be put into `/js/init.js` and have to be write directly in this template. So how should I write them?

Example:http://www.kannewyork.com/test.html its not work.

Comment: "For some reason it cant be put into /js/init.js" ... what does this mean? What happens if you put this directly into your `init.js` file?

Comment: Can you write code in the template but after importing `requirejs`?

Comment: @brianvaughn Because every page has the same header template and they all use `init.js`, but only for login page it use this section.

Comment: @AnatoliyArkhipov I tried and it's not work. As `$` is from jquery which is loaded by requirejs. So this code wont work as when it's loaded directly in the page, jquery is still on the way. isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `require` function as many times as you need. So you should put your code after importing `requirejs` and write something like this:

```
require(['jquery'], function($){
    $(function(){
        $('#loginForm').submit(function(){
            return false;
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: I tried `<script data-main="init" src="require.js"></script>
<font>aa</font>
<script>
require(['jquery', 'login'],function($, login){
 $('font').html('bbb');
});
</script>
` but it's not work: http://www.kannewyork.com/test.html

Comment: Actually, I do not know, where is `jquery` on your server (http://prntscr.com/69yqvg) so you should change the path to jquery in my example. The same problem with the `login` script, specify the correct path to it.

Comment: Thanks you pointed the missed part. I shouldn't use data-main as there is a config inside.